# Ajax and Places API get request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-places-api

I can't get an AJAX request to Google Places API to work. Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'query' : "restaurants+in+" + cityname,
        'key' : MyPublicKey,
        'sensor' : "false"
    },
    success: function(restaurans) {
        console.log(restaurants);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you receiving any error? Anything on network tab on chrome console?

Comment: nothing, the ajax functions isn't even called

Comment: tried with https url ?

Comment: yes, same result (aka no result)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the REST API cannot be used like this (I guess one reason should be CORS)

See [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

> Looking to use this service in a JavaScript application? Check out the
>   Places Library of the Google Maps API v3.

which should lead you to

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

and its "Text Search Requests" section providing examples with a google text search service object